# Getting an error when trying to display multiple html pages (express)

Tags: javascript, express

I have an index.html with a link called 'About'. When clicking on About, I only get the error Cannot GET /about. What is wrong here?

My code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/',function(req,res){
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html'));
});

router.get('/about',function(req,res){
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/about.html'));
});

app.use('/', router);
app.listen(process.env.port || 3000);
console.log('Running at Port 3000');
```

in index.html:

```
<a href="/about">About</a>
```

Comment: Can you show the `<a>` you've used?

Comment: @ChrisG <a href="/about">About</a>

Comment: Using your exact code works fine for me. Does it say `http://localhost:3000/about` in the address bar?

Comment: @ChrisG It seems to be working now.. Strange :D

Comment: Did you restart the server after adding the `/about` route?

Comment: Edits to your code and question may invalidate questions and answers. Please read [When should I make edits to code?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260245)

Answer (score 0):

you can create static folder name public. After you can use this middlewear.
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

Now you can take your index.html and about.html into this new folder which name "public".
After this i think all problem will solved.

[Static Files Examples](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html#serving-static-files-in-express)

[Routing Examples](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)

Comment: While it is true that setting up a folder for static files is preferable (and using views is arguably even better), this doesn't really address OP's issue.